# How to prove that $\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{d}+\frac{d^2}{a}\right) \geq \sqrt[4]{\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4}{4}}$

Tags: inequality

Prove that $$\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{d}+\frac{d^2}{a}\right) \geq \sqrt[4]{\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4}{4}}, \forall a,b,c,d \gt 0 $$ thanks.

Comment: Show please your attempts

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: **please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem**. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: A stronger one is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829520/prove-this-by-inequality-with-four-variables-inequality/3300298#3300298

Comment: @Macavity: You are right, I mixed-up $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ and $a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4$.

Comment: @Macavity: What about this one https://math.stackexchange.com/q/852070/42969? But the only answer seems to be (admittedly) incomplete.

Comment: @Martin Indeed that’s a duplicate, though the answer as you say is unsatisfactory.

Comment: I have provided an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3566860/317854

Comment: @Andreas  Nice. BW is powerful. Some months ago, I used the same BW (none 'standard') to solve some inequalities (although I did not post my solution). For example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079934/prove-that-sum-limits-cyc-fraca4b-geq-sum-limits-cyca325-prod-limit

Comment: @Andreas  Did you solve the stronger one?

Comment: @Andreas  If you are interested in my some posts about the OP, refer to: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193753/this-inequality-why-cant-solve-it-by-now-only-four-variables-inequality/337243#337243,  and  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h366320p12199188

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks for the links. I had seen the mathoverflow one (and commented) but will look at the other problems.